# Autodesk Forge Viewer storing files on local server?

Tags: java, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Can anyone tell me if this is possible with Autodesk Forge Viewer and Model Derivative

- User has dwg and rvt files
- Those files are sent to the Autodesk buckets
- Those files are then sent jobs to convert them to formats that the autodesk forge viewer can display (f2d,svf)
- The converted files are downloaded

Is it then possible to store those converted files on the local server and still have the autodesk forge viewer display them?

Any links or docs on the matter would be appreciated. Also we are a java devs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, use the [Extractor](http://extract.autodesk.io/) to generate the files you need "offline" (on your server). See instructions.

**EDIT**

Updated [ReadMe link](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/master/README.md) (seem comments).

Comment: yes it also seemed to help with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues I was having since all resources are on same server.

Comment: I am now running the Extractor on a local node.js server.   It is not able to create the bucket . Console log of "Failed to create bucket!"   I am wondering if maybe it is not getting a token that has bucket write access? something like data:read data:write bucket:create bucket:read


Here is the console output
    C:\tools\extract.autodesk.io-master>node start.js
    Refreshing Autodesk Service token
    ...
    Token: {"..."}

    POST done Floor_Plan_Sample.dwg ...
    master: 438148-Floor_Plan_Sampledwg
    Failed to create bucket!

Comment: did you try create the bucket manually (via cURL or Postman) with the same permissions? Also, did you change the bucket name (to something unique)?

Comment: It looks like the credentials.js does not pass in the scope. Once I added the scope it seems to work 
    credentials: {
      client_id: process.env.CONSUMERKEY || 'xxx',
      client_secret: process.env.CONSUMERSECRET || 'xxx',
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      scope: 'data:read data:write bucket:create bucket:read'
    },